# Where can I find the correct POH for my Cessna 152?

Tags: student-pilot, cessna-152

I'm training in a C152 and the POH in the backseat has seen its days and I can barely use it, much less keep it from being getting worse than it is. This is a 1983 C152 Trainer aircraft. A lot of questions that I am doing in my flight planning and solo quizzes can be answered through the POH but because the plane is shared I don't want to take it out of the cockpit because it would anger other pilots who also need it. Is there a resource online I can find the POH? Also, I'm not sure but I figure I can't use any C152 POH, it has to be the one for my year and model, is that true too?

Comment: You may take a picture of the important pages, such as weight and balances, speed limits etc. With today's technology that's pretty easy to accomplish.

Comment: @kevin that never crossed my mind because I DON'T want just weight and balance, etc...I want the POH so I can just sit down and read it. Considering that I never owned an airplane and the POH seems pretty important..I think I'd like to have a moment and read the material and not just a few pages that I don't even know are important unless listed by people like you. Thank you for your answer but not so much.

Comment: I see. In that case you may ask your flight school if they have a copy of the POH, or you can just find the POH of another C152 *as reference*. You'd want to match the model, avionics, engine power etc. as close as possible to the one you're flying. C152 is a simple aircraft and *most* sections in a POH would apply to all aircraft, not just a specific airframe.

Comment: @kevin thank you for the info.

Answer (score 7):

Strictly speaking the [POH/AFM](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/what-is-the-difference-between-a-poh-and-an-afm) is specific to your airframe as it generally contains the weight and balance information which will be unique to your airframe as it is equipped. Thus you should always reference the POH that is in the plane for the most accurate source of information.

For example here is a nice [scanned PDF of a POH for a C152](https://www.redskyventures.org/doc/cessna-poh/Cessna_152_152-1980-PIM-S1_to_7-scanned.pdf). You should confirm that the numbers match those in the POH for the airframe. As long as they do you can use it for reference. The POH does not need to match for the specific year but it does need to match for the given aircraft configuration and setup in regards to the engine and performance data as well as any data related to things like extended range tanks etc.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. So how would I know what my aircraft configuration and setup is to be able to tell which reference material will match my aircraft? Is it in on a page on the POH in the cockpit or somewhere? Thank you for your answer, it was illuminating.

Comment: Your aircraft should have an Airworthiness Certificate somewhere. This will denote the model at least and may reveal some engine data depending on how they number their models. The accompanying POH should have the rest of the relevant information.